# Netbeans / PHP code completion on sub class

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion

An issue that has been bugging me for ages now. A bit hard to explain well in my not so fluent english, so please bear with me.

Since I am a lazy programmer I work with Netbeans IDE, cause I love code completion. To have Netbeans hint me the right properties and methods (and just because I consider it good practice), I add a nice PHPdoc block above every method or property, like so:

```
/**
 * My method
 *
 * Some explanation that will show up as a hint,
 * perhaps even with a <code>Example</code
 *
 * @param bool $flag
 * @return self
 */
public function doSomething($flag) {
     ...
     return $this;
}
```

This works great, I get what I expect when it comes to code completion, until I start extending the classes. For example

```
abstract class Parent {
   /** 
    * @return self
    */
   public function parentMethod() {
        ...
        return $this
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   /** 
    * @return self
    */
   public function childMethod() {
        ...
        return $this
   }
}
```

If I now say
`new Child()->`
Netbeans will suggest me the methods from both Parent and Child. If I then do
`new Child()->childMethod()->`
I will still get all the methods from Child and Parent.

> As soon as I use a method that returns itself, and is only
>   declared on the Parent class, I will only get suggestions for
>   methods that are implemented on the Parent class.

So to continue with the example, if I do
`new Child()->parentMethod()->`
I will only get `parentMethod` as a type hint, while `childMethod` is still available and should therefore be suggested as well.

I have searched all over the web but can not find any solution to this (`@return $this` has the exact same result). Is this a bug in Netbeans, or am I doing something wrong? Has anyone found a workaround for this (without adding `@var` after every line)?

*(I currently work on Mac OSX 10.9 with Netbeans 8.0, but OSX 10.7 and 10.8 with Netbeans 7.2, 7.3 and 7.4 had the same problem)*

Comment: Because infinite count of classes can inherit one abstract class, the suggestion is based on the class name, but not from the current created instance. So `ChildClass` has all the methods from self and from base, but method from base returning `$this` can have suggestion only from its own class scope. The doc hints are static, not dynamic

Comment: @RoyalBg that is indeed what is happening, that much was clear. The question is, how do I make it *dynamic* as you call it. It should not be that hard I suppose. Or am I the only one returning `$this` all the time? (Wether the parent class is abstract or not is completely irrelevant btw)

Comment: No, but returning `$this` from parent class for the thing that scans the doc and builds the autocomplete is returning the class where it is declared. It actually scans the classname, instead of object. Pretty much if you say `$class = 'MyClass'; $obj = new $class;` you will get no autocompletion for `$obj->`. As well as you won't get the right autocomplete from a factory i.e. If you are returning `ObjOne` on one condition and `ObjTwo` on another condition, you need to declare both of them as return type.

Comment: see also https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=245129

Comment: Wish you luck, but I guess it's causa perduta. First of all PHP does not compile. So types during coding are pseudo. Predicting types, not classes, will need a interpretation of the code while codding. Which, up to me, will be a huge performance issue for your IDE. Autocompletion in Netbeans 8 is slow enough :D

Comment: For anyone still reading this, I switched to PHPstorm, which does not have this issue. And it has a ton of other great features that Netbeans doesn't support. It does cost a bit, but it is worth every penny imo for someone that uses his IDE on a daily base.

Comment: SOVLED - quick answer is Netbeans 9.0 or read [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53110619/10593659)